# jQuery mobile: can data-role be applied to the body tag?

Tags: jquery

Can `data-role="page"` be applied to the `body` tag instead of a `div` tag? Really just a quirk about adding extra divs that do the same thing as other tags. However I may be wrong about the purpose of body verses a `div` tag with `data-role="page"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it is absolutely okay to add `data-*` attributes to the body tag.
However, this is non intended for `data-role=page` in jQuery mobile. Check out [Anatomy of a Page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html) in the jQuery Mobile docs.

Summary: Don't do it. The extra div tag doesn't hurt and avoids weird problems.